# Java Transformer class duplicates some xml node attributes when transforming

Tags: java, xml, attributes, duplicates, transformer-model

I have created this simple function in Java:

```
public static String prettify(Document xml) {
   String resultValue;
   StreamResult xmlOutput;

    try {
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        xmlOutput = new StreamResult(stringWriter);
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(); 
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "5");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "no");

        Source source = new DOMSource(xml);

        transformer.transform(source, xmlOutput); 
        resultValue = xmlOutput.getWriter().toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        resultValue = "";
    }
    return resultValue;
}
```

It is a very simple function so I can get an indented XML. The problem is that with this specific case, it is duplicating the attributes at the document element... weird. The case is an XML Document with this XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?><Document xmlns='urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'><CstmrDrctDbtInitn><GrpHdr>A</GrpHdr></CstmrDrctDbtInitn></Document>
```

I get:

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
      <GrpHdr>
        A
      </GrpHdr>
 </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
```

As you can see, both attributes at the  are duplicated! I have tried playing with output properties, and nothing. 
If I add, for example, another attribute to the , say "test='whatever'", that specific attribute is NOT duplicated.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I get the expected behavior. Can you detect the actual implementations of the Transformer and DocumentBuilder classes?

Comment: @forty-two, the Transformer.java class used says: Jeff Suttor, 1.3 $, $Date: 2005/10/12 17:14:20 $... The DocumentBuilder class says the same author and version 1.5 (2005/11/21)

Comment: That looks old. What library are you using? What JDK? Have you tried the stuff bundled with the JDK?

Comment: It is JDK 1.6, but I have to get stick to that JDK, can't upgrade. I see that the Transformer class I'm using is in a JAR jaxp-api-1.4.jar Can I upgrade the Transformer and keep working with JDK 1.6? Which is the Transformer class you recommend?

Comment: I correct my last comment... I'm not using  jaxp-api-1.4.jar for the Transformer class... I just removed that JAR from libraries and it doesnt throw any error. I right clicked on the code at the javax.xml.transform.Transformer statement, selected "Navigate > Go to source" and the file is located in the jdk_1.6\src.zip, so, is the only way to upgrade the Transformer class, upgrading the JDK?

Comment: No, you can use the latest Xerces and Xalan libraries. If they are on the classpath, they shoudl override the ones in the JDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @forty-two for your support. I downloaded latest version of Xalan (2.7.2) from http://ftp.cixug.es/apache/xalan/xalan-j/binaries/ and added libraries:

```
serializer.jar
xalan.jar
xercesImpl.jar
xml-apis.jar
```

to my project and now, evrything works as expected.